# Feedly and RSS whickj only provide 3 latest item

Tags: rss, feed, feed-reader

I have access to an rss feed which only provide the 3 latest article of a blog.

However I have noticed that when I check this rss via feedly, feedly save these 3 item for later access.

Is there a way to make feedly auto-save the item during the day, so that when I check my feedly in the evening, I have all the item of the day (maybe 10 items...) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is certainly that Feedly only visits your feed one's a day (wich is quite surprising), so you only get the 3 last items.

To avoid this (and without coding) you could try to build an IFTTT recipe from your RSS feed (Feed channel in IFTTT) and publish it to Blogger (Blogger channel in IFTTT). The feed of Blogger have a 20 items "depth", wich would fit the rhythm of Feedly. Let's hope that IFTTT scraps the feed several times a day.

You'll subscribe this feed in Feedly.

Note that Inoreader offers a feature where you can "boost" the feed scraping frequency.

Could you share the URL of this feed with us to consider other solutions?

Comment: in fact I am completing a existing rss feed, which has a lot of item but is incomplete http://news.korben.info/feed after the competition, I have good item but only 3 of them http://ftr.fivefilters.org/makefulltextfeed.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.korben.info%2Ffeed&max=3 I will try the iftt solution this WE, thanks, do I need to buy Feedly premium to apply your iftt solution?

Comment: Oh OK! That's not a site or Feedly limitation but it's the free version of Fivefilters wich is limited to 3 items. For 20$ (one time for all) you could use the self-hosted version of Fivefilters!

Comment: yay the workaround work well :) even with the paid version you have only 10 item. With this method I have 20 item!

Comment: Great! Happy that it's working well!